# Eclipse plugin saving metadata

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin and I need to save some properties files and binary files as metadata of the plugin. The idea is that when the user starts Eclipse next day he/she won't need to configure/type all again from scratch.

I'm good about writing and reading the files, but I'm not sure about the best location for them. It seems like the *perfect* location would be something like:

```
<WORKSPACE_HOME>/.metadata/.plugins/org.myplugin.name
```

But how do I get or assemble this path? So far I've got to assemble this path as shown below:

- `<WORKSPACE_HOME>`: I could use `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation()`.
- `.metadata/.plugins`: Should I hard code this section? Could it change in the future?
- `org.myplugin.name`: This is the easy one since it's my plugin name.

Is it possible to get that path without hard coding values?

Do I need to create the last directory (my plugin name)? (I guess I need to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform` for your `Bundle`'s "private" state location. If you have a plug-in activator, you can get the `Bundle` from there. Otherwise, there's a different method on `Platform` to get the right instance based on the ID.

https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform.html#getStateLocation-org.osgi.framework.Bundle-

Comment: Works! I got the IPath for the **private** area now. Can I just write and read files there using the **resources** methods?

Comment: No, the resources APIs are only for files in the *workspace model*, which excludes everything under `.metadata`. You can calculate paths under the one you're given using the `IPath` methods and then use `#toFile()` when it's time to work with them as `java.io.File`s.

Comment: Great, I'll try it out.

Comment: Works. Accepting answer.